# Sharing classes between android client and GAE Endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, client-server, google-cloud-endpoints

1)I made a dependency out of model module, inside it there's a `UserModel` class. But I can't import it to client side because my endpoints api `getUser` method returns `com.example.serjsmor.backend.userModelApi.model.UserModel`, and not `com.serjsmor.digitalpheromone.module.UserModel`. I can import this generated class to my client but then what's the point of my dependency ?

2) Any changes I do `UserModel` doesn't affect the backend generated class (like adding another `Ctor`). How can I make the backend to recompile it again after a change ? (tried to add/remove, rebuild, clean etc.)

I'm using Android Studio 1.02 on Yosemite

client code :

```
package com.serjsmor.digitalpheromone;

import com.example.serjsmor.backend.userModelApi.UserModelApi;
import com.example.serjsmor.backend.userModelApi.model.UserModel;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;
import com.serjsmor.digitalpheromone.module.UserAlreadyExistsException;
import com.serjsmor.digitalpheromone.module.UserNotFoundException;
import com.serjsmor.digitalpheromone.pheromones.Pheromone;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EndpointsServer implements Server {

    private static final String TAG = "EndpointsServer";

    final UserModelApi userEndpointsApi;

    public EndpointsServer() {
        UserModelApi.Builder builder = new UserModelApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
                });

        userEndpointsApi = builder.build();

    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String email)  {
        User  user = null;
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "in getUser with email " +email);
            // get user from db
            UserModel userModel = userEndpointsApi.getUserModel(email).execute();
            if (userModel != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "user != null with email " + email);
                user = new User(userModel);
            }
            else { // add user to db
                Log.d(TAG, "user == null with email " + email);
                user = new User(email);
                UserModel afterInsert = userEndpointsApi.storeUserModel(user.getUserModel()).execute();
                Log.d(TAG, "after insert user email" + afterInsert.getEmail());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

Endpoint :

```
package com.example.serjsmor.myapplication.backend;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Transaction;
import com.serjsmor.digitalpheromone.module.UserAlreadyExistsException;
import com.serjsmor.digitalpheromone.module.UserModel;
import com.serjsmor.digitalpheromone.module.UserNotFoundException;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Named;


/**
 * An endpoint class we are exposing
 */
@Api(
        name = "userModelApi",
        version = "v1",
        resource = "userModel",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "backend.myapplication.serjsmor.example.com",
                ownerName = "backend.myapplication.serjsmor.example.com",
                packagePath = ""
        )
)
public class UserModelEndpoint {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserModelEndpoint.class.getName());

    /**
     * This method gets the <code>UserModel</code> object associated with the specified <code>email</code>.
     *
     * @param email The id of the object to be returned.
     * @return The <code>UserModel</code> associated with <code>id</code>.
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "getUserModel")
    public UserModel getUserModel(@Named("email") String email) throws UserNotFoundException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "serj.pheromone.BeanEndpoint inside getUserModel");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "serj.pheromone.BeanEndpoint email" + email);
        DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        UserModel user = null;
//        throw new UserNotFoundException();
        try {
            Key k = KeyFactory.createKey(UserModel.class.getSimpleName(), email);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "serj.pheromone.BeanEndpoint key ");
            Entity entity = datastoreService.get(k);
            user = new UserModel();
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setNickname((String) entity.getProperty("nickname"));

        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            return null;

        }

        return user;
    }




 }
```

Model dependency :

```
package com.serjsmor.digitalpheromone.module; 

import com.serjsmor.digitalpheromone.module.PheromoneModel;
import java.util.List;


public class UserModel {

    protected String email;
    protected String nickname;
    protected List<PheromoneModel> pheromoneList;

    public UserModel() {

    }

    public UserModel(String email, String nickname) {
        this.email = email;
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public UserModel(String email, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.email = email;
        this.nickname = firstName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public List<PheromoneModel> getPheromoneList() {
        return pheromoneList;
    }

    public void setPheromoneList(List<PheromoneModel> pheromoneList) {
        this.pheromoneList = pheromoneList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to answer, I had a mysterios compelation error that wasn't surfaced until I started manually all gradle tasks and specially the getClientLibs task. [More on debugging gradle](http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2014/06/23/how-to-debug-gradle-script/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the answer, even though I have encountered the same issue. However, you can such get rid of this ambiguous class from the backend, by making use of Google's Gson library. For example, if you have Grocery.class in your app, and you have GroceryBackend.class in your backend, and if you're sure that both the classes have same fields, then do the following:

```
Gson groceryGson = new Gson();
Grocery grocery = groceryGson.fromJson(groceryGson.toJson(groceryBackend), Grocery.class);
```